# JSP request.getParameter string

Tags: java, string, jsp

I have the following page in JSP:

```
<%
    String req = request.getParameter("req");

    if (req == "Start")
        // Do something here
%>

<form>
    <input type="submit" name="req" value="Start" />
</form>
```

But when I press the *Start* button it seems that *req* value is not equal to *Start*, and the code does not enters the *if* statement.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should write

```
 if (req != null && req.equals("Start"))
```

instead of

```
 if (req == "Start")
```

Comment: Because in your code it is comparing objects. For comparing the objects you have to use the methpd `equals`, otherwise it will compare it by the reference.

Comment: +1, `"Start".equals(req)` is also used often, although I don't like the awkward syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`if("Start".equals(request.getParameter("req")))`

Even if request.getParameter("req") is null, you won't receive any errors.

Answer (score 1):

`if (req == "Start")` comparing the references of both object thats why you are not entering in if block. Use String class `equals()` method which compare the values instead of reference.